# How do I prevent Quality loss in the beginning of a video?

Tags: codec, ffmpeg, video-quality, quality, transcoding

My company transcodes videos sent in by users (recorder by our own screenrecording software)

I use FFMpeg to do the work using this command:

```
 /ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i in.mov -vcodec libx264 -fpre /ffmpeg/ffpresets/libx264-slower.ffpreset   -y out.flv
```

The purpose is to prepare the video for viewing in browser.

**The problem is that the first 10, or so, seconds the quality is really poor.**

### What can cause this? and how can i fix it?

Preset settings:

```
coder=1
flags=+loop
cmp=+chroma
partitions=+parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8
me_method=umh
subq=8
me_range=16
g=250
keyint_min=25
sc_threshold=40
i_qfactor=0.71
b_strategy=2
qcomp=0.6
qmin=0
qmax=69
qdiff=4
bf=3
refs=5
directpred=3
trellis=1
flags2=+bpyramid+mixed_refs+wpred+dct8x8+fastpskip
wpredp=2
rc_lookahead=50
```

Exampel of an input video

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '84f42bcb67ac616635ef6f99057bbbc46d418295.mov':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2012-03-07 13:45:16
  Duration: 00:15:56.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4108 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: qtrle, rgb24, 1680x945, 3401 kb/s, 13.61 fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-07 13:45:16
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-07 13:45:16
```

Comment: Any chance you could post an example, both of input and of the poor-quality output? Would help trying to tweak it (and reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by updating FFMpeg to newer version